# [Android ]App Restarting after device reboot

Tags: android, startup, reboot

My app is restarting in the background when the device reboots or if switched on after power off. I do not understand the reason behind it. I have not used android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED in my app neither I have registered any service to alarm manager. I have tried rebooting the device after manually killing the device, then also it is starting the background and making api calls. I tested it on Android 6.0 and 7.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "App restarting after device reboot" - how? A service or the app itself? Do you use any services or BroadcastRecievers? Add your manifest to your question

Comment: I only have GCM Receiver in the app. Thats why , I am also confused.

Comment: You have to add some code, otherwise no one can help. Add manifest and the receiver

Comment: ok. Just a quick question though. Does having any BroadcastReceiver in the app restarts it on the device reboot?

Comment: Not unless you have any intent filters, such as BOOT_COMPLETE, SCREEN_ON, etc

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason behind it. One of the libraries: org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.5.1 has StartupBroadcastReceiver in its AndroidManifest.xml. Hence, my app was starting on the reboot.